# UnKnown Coordinate Reference System on GeoServer

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, geoserver, geo

I have created one workspace and after that created a store and Include one shape file for the state Charleston, SC, USA. Here I attached Screenshot for geoserver coordinate system.

[image: Coordinate Reference System]
I'm getting Native SRS as **UNKNOWN** How to resolve this ????

Comment: You can simply set the crs in declared box.

Comment: Thankyou ! It works ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means that GeoServer has been unable to determine the correct EPSG code for your data set, often because it was written by ESRI software using a different interpretation of the standard than the rest of the world uses.

A quick search on epsg.io gives [EPSG:2273](http://epsg.io/2273) which can be entered in the declared SRS box.

Comment: i have another query also . I have a file with .kmz extension. How to convert .kmz into .Zip. Geoserver accepts only .zip. then how can i import .kmz File ???

Comment: please accept this answer if it answers your question and then ask a new question about kml/z files